# ASP.NET authentication against Windows Azure Active Directory gives ACS50001 error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

> ACS50001: Relying party with identifier `https://localhost:44304/` was not found when I try to sign-in with my web site against WAAD.

What might I be doing wrong here? I've tried this over and over, following the instructions carefully:

1. Create ASP.NET 4.5 MVC web site in VS2012, Intranet template.
2. Configure web app for SSL - Enable SSL, and set startup URL to `https://localhost:44304`
3. Register app in Azure portal under Integrated Apps - App URL, App ID URI, and Reply URI all set to: `https://localhost:44304/`
4. Run Identity and Access against VS2012 project.
5. Copy metadata fields from WAAD portal into wizard, and click OK:

   > STS metadata document path:  https://login.windows.net/06c6c283-5c4b-40c5-ac5c-21d2ff4364a3/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
   >
   > App ID URI: `https://localhost:44304/`
6. When I launch app (first time, or after a reboot), I get the expected sign-in dialog. After signing in as one of my users, I get the ACS50001 error described above. If I try subsequently to again run the app, I get the error ACS50001 immediately (no sign-in dialog).

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that the Realm under Relying party application is "https://localhost:44304/" (*This field is case sensitive)

Comment: Have you found any Solution, yet?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by making sure my Relying party and app URI were an **exact** match. I had a trailing slash on the relying party (or audienceUri) that I needed to remove.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My issue is same configuration works fine with one AD and doesn't work with other AD(which is actual Microsoft AD)

Answer (score 3):

i had similar problem.

and i solved it by giving permisssion to Application.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to Azure Portal - then Click on Azure AD
2. Go to your Applications
3. Click on Configure
4. Move to last Section - permissions to other applications
5. Click on Application Permission in Window Azure Active Directory Row
6. Select your permission.
7. And then Click on Save

Here i am attaching below screenshot , which shows where i have set my permission

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to specific a view to the URL

```
https://localhost:44304/callback
```